# Google directions with php variable

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3

Hello im trying to get google directions working with geo location, i have the geolocation part done, and it links in with directions and that works fine, the issue is when i try to make it dynamic so it gets directions for different objects for different pages ut i just cannot get it to work i thoguht i could jsut echo a varible in the destintion spection and that would be it but it doesnt work, in the source code the destintion is the varible not the content. Heres my code

```
<?php $rows = mysql_fetch_array($results) or die(mysql_error());
    echo '<script>';
        echo 'if (navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                var mapOptions ={
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: coords,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions:{
                        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                    },
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById(\'panel\'));
                var request = {
                    origin: coords,';
                    $geo = $rows['GEO'];
                echo 'destination: \'$geo\',
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                };
                directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, \'load\', initialize);';
    echo '</script>';
?>
```

If anyone can see what im doing wrong please let me know, thanks for the help.

EDIT

my query (works at it shows everything else on the page)

```
$id = $_GET["id"] ;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Posts where id = $id" ;
$results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

in the database GEO isnt geo location it's just a name like a town, or shop etc.

Comment: I would generally recommend echoing such a large block of code, but you also can't embed a variable in a string with single quotes, only double.

Comment: ^ "not echoing" is what I meant to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue you have is with the single quoted string, but you should probably look into using a [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) format.

This will give you the correct out of `$geo` in your string:

```
 echo "destination: '$geo',";
```

Using [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) makes it generally easier to read:

```
$geo = $rows['GEO'];
$html = <<<HTML
<script>
if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: coords,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions:{
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
        var request = {
            origin: coords,
            destination: '$geo',
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
HTML;
echo $html;
```

Comment: Thank you, i changed it to the double then singles and it worked, much appreciated.

Comment: Check out my edit using the HEREDOC format, it is usually much easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Php variables are ignored if you echo with '. Use " like this:

```
            $geo = $rows['GEO'];
            echo 'destination: '."\'$geo\'".',
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };
```